# Guidance for creating jquery promise hierarchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to delay-load some assets for a website. I'm very new to promises but they seem to be very helpful in this context. Specifically, I've got the below method I created to download both the HTML and CSS files, and then flip a KnockoutJS observable indicating that the section is then available. That method looks like this:

```
function delayDownloadAssets(sectionName) {
var htmlRequest = $.ajax({ url: 'http://www.example.com/' + sectionName + '.html' }),
cssRequest = $.ajax({ url: 'http://www.example.com/' + sectionName + '.css'  });

$.when(firstRequest, secondRequest).done(function (firstResponse, secondResponse) {
    //Insert HTML assets and CSS assets into DOM
    app.sections[sectionName].enabled(true);
});
}
```

I can then call the method a few times like:

```
delayDownloadAssets("Section1");
delayDownloadAssets("Section2");
delayDownloadAssets("Section3");
```

So far, so good. But I'd like to wrap all three section download calls in a similar way, so that I can take action. Something like:

```
$.when(delayDownloadAssetsCall1, delayDownloadAssetsCall2,delayDownloadAssetsCall3).done(function () {
    alert('Web site download is entirely complete!');
});
```

I hope that this question is clear, but if it needs any clarification, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work as is if you just return the $.when result:

```
function delayDownloadAssets(sectionName) {
    var htmlRequest = $.ajax({ url: 'http://www.example.com/' + sectionName + '.html' }),
        cssRequest = $.ajax({ url: 'http://www.example.com/' + sectionName + '.css'  });

    //add return here
    return $.when(firstRequest, secondRequest).done(function (firstResponse, secondResponse) {
        //Insert HTML assets and CSS assets into DOM
        app.sections[sectionName].enabled(true);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What a simple solution. I'll accept as soon as SO allows it.

Answer (score 1):

With `delayDownloadAssets` written as indicated by Esailija, you can go further :

```
function loadSections(sections) {
    return $.when.apply(null, sections.map(delayDownloadAssets));
}
```

Call as follows :

```
var sections = ["Section1", "Section2", "Section3"];

loadSections(sections).then(function() {
    //Web site download is entirely complete!
});
```

Comment: Can you help me understand the use of "then" here instead of "done"?

Comment: In jQuery the differences are that; (a) .then() accepts two callbacks - success and error, (b) .then() possesses "filtering power" - the callbacks' return values get passed on down the promise chain in the form of a new promise, whereas done ignores any return value and passes on its input promise in exactly the same state. (In promises/A+ implementations, .done() has a distinctly different meaning from that of jQuery's .done()). I tend not to use jQuery's .done() - it's a bit of a "rebel without a cause".

Answer (score 0):

why not just chain the 3 with done functions.

i.e. the first call's done function calls the second and the second call's done function calls the third and finally in the third call's done function do what ever you would like.

UPDATE:

to run in paralel you would need async code.
First create a global

```
var doneFlag = 0;
```

I would then call each using setTimeout with a done function that only contains

```
doneFlag++;
```

Then a fourth setTimeout function that calls a simple loop

```
while(doneFlag != 3)
{
   var x = 5+5; //just to keep from crashing js 
}
//any code you want to run after complete dl of all.
```

Comment: Because he wants to run them in parallel.

Comment: To echo SLaks: That would work, but likely by running the downloads in parallel, they would complete more quickly. (Or that's my hope anyway)

Comment: I did not take away from post to run in parallel.  see update